# Version incompatibility between Lucene and Solr

Tags: lucene, solr, version

We have an index generated using the 3.0.2 Lucene jar. The Solr version I installed and configured is 1.4.1. In Solr's lib directory I see that Lucene 2.9.3 is used by Solr.

At startup an exception is thrown: "Incompatible format version: 2 expected 1 or lower". I am guessing it is possibly due to incompatible Lucene versions - 3.0.2 was used to generate the index and 2.9.3 is being used to read the index.

Am I missing a configuration step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to downgrade Lucene to 2.9.x or upgrade Solr to 3.x/4.x (trunk) which uses a more recent Lucene version.